# Dynamically created array length in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-admin

I have an array like this coming from the API:

```
[
{
    "clicks": {
        "2019-01": [
            {
                "clicks": "194",
                "type": 0,
                "user": 19
            },
            {
                "clicks": "414",
                "type": 0,
                "user": 19
            },
            {
                "clicks": "4",
                "type": 90,
                "user": 20
            },
            {
                "clicks": "3",
                "type": 90,
                "user": 21
            }
        ],
        "2019-02": [
            {
                "clicks": "2",
                "type": 2,
                "user": 17
            },
            {
                "clicks": "1",
                "type": 1,
                "user": 19
            }
        ]
    }
}
]
```

I want to count all the clicks in each month.

i wrote this so far:

```
const MyMonthlyClickCount = ({ record }) => {
    console.log("bla", record);
    var fLen, i, myMonth;
    fLen = record.id.length;
    myMonth = record.id;
    for (i =0; i < fLen; i++) {
       var ads, all, phone, z, mLen;
       mLen = `record.clicks.${myMonth[i].yearmonth}`.length;
       console.log("mLen:", mLen);
    }
    return (<StatusTextField source="record.clicks.2019-01.name" statusK="valami" />)
}
```

however mLen does not do what I want from it.  It currently counts the characters in the string.

I want mLen to give me back the array length.

How can I do that?

output of console.log:

```
bla {clicks: {…}, id: Array(2)}
clicks: 2019-01: (32) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2019-02: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object
id: (2) [{…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object

mLen: 21
```

Comment: Reka, are you simply trying to sum all the `clicks` for each month?

Comment: yes, but i have the arrays monthly, so e.g. clicks.2019-01.clicks (which i have 6 per the console.log output), and clicks.2019-02.clicks (I have 32 entries in 2019-02)

Comment: Sorry, to be clear. There are multiple `clicks` objects with duplicate months?

Comment: yes, so e.g. i want to sum evert clicks within clicks.2019-01 (I have 32x clicks in it, in the example data i have 2x: "clicks:47" and "clicks:459") I want to sum it as "in 2019-01 i had 506 clicks".

Comment: Sounds good, give me a mo. Reka, to be clear that outside `[]` is what is adding confusion here.

Comment: ah, and i have 12 months in a year ;) So of course max month number is 12 per year. So I want maximum 12 rows with the summary of the clicks in each month)

Comment: Ah, so the out is each year ?

Comment: no, monthly. but this is not relevant. I have this array: clicks.2019-01, and i want to count the values of the clicks in it. IT doesn't matter how many months do I have, I does matter tho that I cannot get the length of the array for some reason, and I get the number of characters in mLen, given react does not treat my variables as object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is worth adding some more data, but here you go.

```js
let rawData = [
  {
    "clicks": {
        "2019-01": [
            {
                "clicks": "47",
                "id": 63,
                "type": 0,
                "user": 5
            },
            {
                "clicks": "459",
                "id": 5,
                "type": 0,
                "user": 5
            }
       ],
        "2019-02": [
            {
                "clicks": "0",
                "id": 44,
                "type": 0,
                "user": 12
            }
         ]
      }
   }
];

const MyMonthlyClickCount = (record) => {
  if(Array.isArray(record) === false) record = [record];
  return record.map(year => {
    let arrMonth = [];
    for(mth in year.clicks) {
      let m = {
        month: mth,
        clicks: year.clicks[mth].reduce((a,v) => a+=parseInt(v.clicks),0)
      };
      arrMonth.push(m);
    }
    return arrMonth;
  });
};



console.log(MyMonthlyClickCount(rawData));
console.log(MyMonthlyClickCount(rawData[0]));
```

Comment: did not work, it said rawData.map is not a function

Comment: Reka, notice in the answer I have set your data to equal `rawData`. Had to do this to get snippet to work. Change `rawData` to whatever variable your data is stored in.

Comment: yes I did that ... I set rawData to record, which I got from my API

Comment: Hang on let me change it so you can just copy.

Comment: Hopefully you can copy the function straight out.

Comment: note you have destructuring in your function, you need to add back. `({ record })`

Comment: still :( it gives me TypeError, with record.map is not a function, but the actual error is at  the sum: clicks: year.clicks[mth].reduce((a,v) => a+=parseInt(v.clicks),0) (the renderer says right after "=>")

Comment: No, I suspect that `record` is not an array. It might be the object with `clicks`. Can you inspect `record` and see what it actually is.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an array, as react-admin's validator expects a json array as a response back from the API. Let me update the original post with the exact response I got back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190333/discussion-between-bibberty-and-reka-karolyi).

Comment: hi Bibberty, could you please join back to the chatroom if you're online?